# Changing Hadoop Block Size lower than minimum block size

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, block

How do I change the Hadoop block size lower than the default minimum block size.

This manual page (https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml) says that by default min block size or `dfs.namenode.fs-limits.min-block-size` is set to 1048576 (1 MB). However, when I change it to any value lower than that, say 100 KB, in the `hdfs-site.xml` and in the same time I changed the `dfs.blocksize` to 200 KB (which is still greater than the modified min block size), I still get the error saying that `dfs.blocksize` can't be lower than min block size of 1048576.

Also, I am using Hadoop 2.7.1, just in case.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the property in `hdfs-site.xml` not in `hdfs-default.xml`. Add the property and restart the namenode and try again.

Comment: My bad, I meant to say I tried it on hdfs-site.xml, not the hdfs-default.xml.

Comment: Have you tried restarting the hadoop services and then run your job?

Comment: I tried restarting services and it still says dfs.blocksize < 1048576. Even though, I set the min block size to be 100 KB.